# How to call a static member with init parameter

Tags: swift

I have a class called WareHouse and a required init()
I would like to call it like the following example, but i dont know how to program it.
Any suggestions?

Warehouse(databaseName:"GoogleService-Info").share.signIn(withEmail:xxxx, withPassword:XXX)

The following is my sample code

```
class WareHouse{

public static let shared = WareHouse(databaseName: "GoogleService-Info-WarehouseDev")
....

required init(databaseName:String) {

    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: databaseName, ofType: "plist")

    if let filePath = filePath {
        let fileopts = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
        FirebaseApp.configure(name: "Warehouse", options: fileopts!)
        app = FirebaseApp.app(name: "Warehouse")

    }     
}
func signIn(withEmail:String, withPassword:String){
}
}
```

Comment: You’re asking to do two opposite things at once. You can call `WareHouse.shared` or you can call `WareHouse(databaseName:)`. You cannot do both! (Actually the first one calls the second one for you.)

Comment: @matt Hi matt, then how can i call with the same instance? e.g. WareHouse("GoogleService-Info-WarehouseDev").signIn() and then
WareHouse("GoogleService-Info-WarehouseDev").fetchData()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may design your **WareHouse** like the one below.

```
class WareHouse {

    private static var wareHouses: [WareHouse] = []

    public static func of(name: String) -> WareHouse {
        if let wareHouse = wareHouses.first(where: { (wareHouse) -> Bool in
            wareHouse.databaseName == name
        }) {
            return wareHouse
        } else {
            let wareHouse = WareHouse(databaseName: name)
            wareHouses.append(wareHouse)
            return wareHouse
        }
    }

    private let databaseName: String

    required init(databaseName:String) {
        self.databaseName = databaseName
    }

    public func yourFunction() {

    }
}
```

And, you can call your function in WareHouse class as,

```
WareHouse.of(name: "").yourFunction()
```

In this way, you can maintain a distinct shared instances of your warehouse class with database name.